# How would i go about adding a product to a category page automatically

Tags: php, html

So I started working on a little site for a client. Originally the requirements were to have about 14 product pages and manual entry of products through html, no cms, just ma and pa stuff.. However over the course of the work, the scope changed to include hundreds of products and now they want a product manager. Im still in school learning PHP so im not the best in the world at it and I wrote the category pages in HTML (http://ra-yon.com/beta/Test_sites/HFE/engagement.php). I made a little product creation page with php to basically insert a couple variables into a template of a preexisting product page. Would there be anyway to add a functionality in php (maybe an append) so it would be added to the end of a category page?

Thanks for the help
- a confused student.

Comment: I think you should move your site to a proper e-Commerce site. Could be your own or use one of the thousands e-Commerce open source apps that are out there. I would not keep going with adding one page for every product, you should use a Database to add the products and only one page to display them

Comment: I kinda figured this was the answer, i was hoping for a shot in the dark. Thank you